# What is the proper syntax of "GO" in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error, sql-server-2014, sql-authentication

I'm attempting to run a script that adds a login to MSSQL it includes two GO commands, both of which yield the error: Msg 102 ... Incorrect syntax near 'GO'. The following example code runs on a database named MyDB

```
DECLARE @currentUsername varchar(30);
DECLARE @password varchar(10);
SET @currentUsername = 'thisisatest';
SET @password = 'mypassword13';

DECLARE @addUser varchar(1000);
SET @addUser = '
    CREATE LOGIN ' + @currentUsername + '
    WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @password + ''',
    DEFAULT_DATABASE = [MyDB]
    GO
    USE MyDB
    CREATE USER ' + @currentUsername + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @currentUsername + '
    EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''' + @currentUsername + '''
    EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datawriter'', ''' + @currentUsername + '''
    GO
';
PRINT @addUser;
EXEC (@addUser);
```

Comment: It may not be the word go but something near it that has incorrect syntax. Could be related to embedded quotes.

Comment: GO is batch terminator, not part of T-SQL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212077/the-proper-use-of-mssql-go-in-vba/32212122#32212122

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly new to MSSQL. I see the GO keyword all over the place in scripts.

Comment: And second thing consider using `EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @sql, @param_list, @args...` instead of concatenating string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299249/what-is-the-use-of-go-in-sql-server-management-studio , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593100/go-command-causing-a-failure-in-a-call-to-exec-function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GO` isn't a regular SQL statement. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> `GO` is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the **sqlcmd** and **osql** utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor.

Try breaking it up into multiple calls like this:

```
DECLARE @currentUsername varchar(30);
DECLARE @password varchar(10);
SET @currentUsername = 'thisisatest';
SET @password = 'mypassword13';

DECLARE @addUser varchar(1000);
SET @addUser = '
    CREATE LOGIN ' + @currentUsername + '
    WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @password + ''',
    DEFAULT_DATABASE = [MyDB]
';
PRINT @addUser;
EXEC (@addUser);

SET @addUser = '
    USE MyDB
    CREATE USER ' + @currentUsername + ' FOR LOGIN ' + @currentUsername + '
    EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datareader'', ''' + @currentUsername + '''
    EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_datawriter'', ''' + @currentUsername + '''
';
PRINT @addUser;
EXEC (@addUser);
```